# Attach an @Observer method to a Java WebSocket ServerEndpoint?

Tags: java, events, websocket, observers

This seemed like such a trivial idea but... I want my Java EE7 WebSocket endpoint to have a method for observing events so that I can send messages back to the browser client when the event fires. It makes sense to put the event on the WebSocket because that's where you can cache the Session when it opens the WebSocket, and use it to send a message back to the right client.

But... If I use a simple @Observes method on the WebSocket, when the event fires it creates a *new* WebSocket instance which does not have the Session cached. Alternately, when I use @Observes(notifyObserver=IF_EXISTS) to try and block the creation of a new WebSocket instance, it doesn't fire at all.

Help? Is it not possible to use a WebSocket endpoint as an event observer? Or is there a better way to route messages back to the client who opened the socket in the first place?

Comment: are you using CDI @Observes? If so, is your WebSocket endpoint CDI enabled class? (Does it have @*Scoped or something like that?). Sharing at least some portion of your code should help, also add about which Java EE container you use. Anyway, what should help is injecting some CDI bean to the endpoint, pass the session there and use that object as an Observer instead endpoint itself.

Comment: Yes, @Observes. I'm using Glassfish 4.0 with Netbeans 7.4. I don't have an explicit scoped attribute on the endpoint because (I thought) it's automatically session-scoped to deal with the end point conversation. I'll try making it explicit, and if that doesn't work, spawning a new pojo bean for event handling with the session cached. It will be a tonight (8 hours) before I can get back to it.

Comment: Ok - this looks like my problem: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-370

Comment: Ok - this basic approach is not going to work until the the WebSocket specification is integrated with CDI. https://java.net/jira/browse/WEBSOCKET_SPEC-196

Comment: And more... https://java.net/jira/browse/JMS_SPEC-121  https://java.net/projects/websocket-spec/lists/jsr356-experts/archive/2013-05/message/1

Comment: Yeah, I know about that, there are some improvements planned for next version of WebSocket specification. Nevertheless, it still should be possible to inject CDI beans, see cdi sample from tyrus workspace: https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/tree/master/samples/cdi . Maybe you can start with that and then try to add @Observes to some convenient place?

Comment: I can inject beans fine into the WebSocket. The problem is when I try to trigger event observer methods on either the beans or the socket itself it always results in a new instance being created (or not working at all if I block new instances, as I described originally.) I can hack around this by just passing along a reference to the socket (or it's associated socket session) to processes that I spawn from the calls to the socket, and send socket messages to the client that way, but that defeats the whole point of having event observers, doesn't it?